# Button Event InfoWindow Google Map APi

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map with custom InfoWindows. Alle InfoWindows have a button which has a anchor link. Each button should open an overlay onclick.

My InfoWindows are set up like this:

```
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<img src="images/villa-heinepark-klein.jpg"/>' +
    '<div class="info_text">' +
    '<h2 class="firstHeading">Villa im Heinepark</h2>' +
    '<p>' +
    '<img src="images/icon-ring.png"/>' +
    'drau&szlig;en unbegrenzt,' +
    '<br>' +
    'drinnen bis zu 90 Personen' +
    '</p>' +
    '<p>' +
    '<img src="images/icon-glass.png"/>' +
     'max. 110 / min. 60 Personen</p>' +
    '<a href="#HEINEPARK" class="button" onclick="myFunction()">> Mehr Informationen</a>' +    
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'],

     ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<img src="images/lutter-wegner-klein.jpg"/>' +
    '<div class="info_text">' +
    '<h2 class="firstHeading">Lutter & Wegner</h2>' +
    '<p>' +
    '<img src="images/icon-ring.png"/>' +
    'ca. 35 Personen sitzend,' +
    '<br>' +
    'bis zu 80 inkl. Stehpl&auml;tze' +
    '</p>' +
    '<p>' +
    '<img src="images/icon-glass.png"/>' +
     'max. 110 / min. 60 Personen</p>' +
    '<a href="#LUTTERWEGNER" class="button">> Mehr Informationen</a>' +    
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'],
```

My Javascript looks like this:

```
function myFunction(e) {
$('.button').click(function() {  
        var anchor = $(this).attr("href");
        //alert(ab);
        $(anchor).show();
        return false;})  }
```

The Problem is you have to click twice and it only works on the first InfoWindow. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance
Jette

Answer (score 0):

You've got both an onclick event on each of your buttons, and a click event handler on  your buttons.  You don't need both.

Get rid of the onclick events, so

```
'<a href="#HEINEPARK" class="button" onclick="myFunction()">> Mehr Informationen</a>'
```

becomes

```
'<a href="#HEINEPARK" class="button">Mehr Informationen</a>'
```

And just setup the click event handlers once, at the same time you're creating your array, i.e. get rid of the `myFunction` part of your code, so you're left with:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function() {  
    var anchor = $(this).attr("href");
    $(anchor).show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, that the infowWindows are loaded whenever you click on a marker. so it wont fire the jquery function. see more under: douglas.madd-agency.de

Comment: I've amended my answer, this way it should detect a click on any element with a `.button` class loaded dynamically into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just figured it out how it works. I changed the javascript to:

```
var int=setInterval('check()', 500);
function check()
{
   if (chkObject('.button')==true)
   { 
    $('.button').click(function() {  
        var anchor = $(this).attr("href");
        //alert(ab);
        $(anchor).show();
        return false;}) 
  }

}

function chkObject(elemId)
{
   return (document.getElementsByClassName('.button'))? true : false;
}
```

So it checks if there is a .button before it does the function. I did take out the onclick in the a-tag. Thank you!